# Additional libraries in Ubuntu Touch (libpng, libfreetype etc.)

Tags: ubuntu-touch, cmake

How do I install & use libfreetype, libpng etc. when developing for Ubuntu Touch? I understand that I need to install them inside chroot. Is there any trick to it, or should I just apt-get install the lot?

And also how do I make CMake find them after I install them? From what I see, scripts like FindFreetype or FindPNG look at specific paths, but libraries and headers in chroot are located at different paths (arm-linux-gnueabihf/...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got it. Ubuntu IDE uses schroot sessions. Those sessions persist even after you reboot your computer, so if such session was created before you installed software into chroot, Ubuntu IDE won't be able to access this software.

So, if you need to install additional libraries into Ubuntu SDK chroot, do the following:

1) Close Ubuntu IDE

2) List old chroot sessions:

```
schroot --list --all-sessions
```

2) Kill old click chroot sessions:

```
sudo schroot --end-session SESSION_NAME
```

3) Login into chroot maintenance mode

```
sudo click chroot -a armhf -f ubuntu-sdk-15.04 maint
```

4) apt-get install necessary libraries and/or software

5) Start Ubuntu IDE again

Answer (score 0):

The chroots are like VMs, so it's just `apt-get install` inside the chroot. The console of the chroot is accessible through the GUI of the SDK or the `schroot` command.

Well-written FindStuff.cmake scripts are finding things correctly (usually they are doing find_library, find_path, pkgconfig, etc.).

Comment: OK, thank you. I installed libpng inside chroot I'm using, and now CMake can find it - but only if I run CMake by myself from console via "click chroot ... run cmake". If I run CMake from Ubuntu SDK IDE (QtCreator fork), it still can't find libpng. It's like it's using a different chroot altogether. I see that when IDE run "click chroot ... run cmake", it uses an auto-generated name for chroot ("click-amrhf-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-{guid}") with a different guid every time. I believe, it still must create those temporary copies of chroot from "source: click-armhf-ubuntu-sdk-15.04", but maybe I'm wrong

Comment: The idea is that the 'source' chroot is like a constant snapshot of the environment. It's editable only when logged into 'source:...'. The compilations create independent temporary sessions from it.